# Container application that rules all the modules

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cordova

I got a new project from the client, it's about enterprise app. My question is, is it possible to create an app is a container application that rules/hold all the modules?

What I mean is the container application is the native app itself but the modules can be native or hybrid. Below is the sample screenshot of the app.

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible to do. Try to utilise native components as many places as possible. Apple will not reject your application.